# Apply javascript to pages like we apply css... wouldn't it be nice?

Tags: javascript

It just crossed my mind that it would be extremely nice to be able to apply javascript code like you can apply css.

Imagine something like:

```
/* app.jss */
div.closeable : click {
  this.remove();
}

table.highlightable td : hover {
  previewPane.showDetailsFor(this);
}

form.protectform : submit { }
links.facebox : click {} 
form.remote : submit {
   postItUsingAjax()... }
```

I'm sure there are better examples.

You can do pretty similar stuff with on dom:loadad -> $$(foo.bar).onClick (but this will only work for elements present at dom:loadad) ... etc. But having a jss file would be really cool.

Well, this has to be a question, not a braindump... so my question is: is there something like that?

**Appendum**

I know Jquery and prototype allow to do similar things with $$ and convenient helpers to catch events. But what I sometimes dislike about this variant is that the handler only gets installed onto elements which have been present when the site first got loaded.

Comment: Better syntax were pseudo selectors like `:click` and `:hover`.

Comment: I do like your syntax better, but again, see jQuery's live events as linked in my answer below. They work beyond what's present at DOM load.

Comment: The live event system looks nice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest thing I've seen to what you're talking about are jQuery's Live Events:

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

They basically will pick up new elements as they're created and add the appropriate handler code you've assigned.

Comment: Exactly.  This addresses both the original question and the appendum.  Live will re-evaluate the selectors and apply the associated javascript each time the DOM changes.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). I don't have the luxury of using where I work, but it looks like this:

```
$("div.closeable").click(function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

That's not too far removed from your first example.

Comment: $('div.closeable').bind('click',function(){this.remove();}); would work... presuming that the actual DOM elements had a .remove() method attached to them.

Comment: to work completely like CSS does... you'd want to use the .live() option to capture future elements created.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jquery](http://jquery.com/). You could have a .js include file that you add to all of your pages and get something very close to what you are describing.

The biggest pitfall would be performance.